# What "sndrcv()" does? - scapy?

Tags: packet, scapy

I asked alot of questions about "how i get HTML code with sendind Get packet" and no one knows the answer:

[I dont get HTTP answer with sr function. Just an ACK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38547323/i-dont-get-the-http-answer-tosr-function-just-the-ack-scapy)

[Why when i send Get Requewst, i got the Ack and not the html code? scapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589694/why-when-i-send-get-requewst-i-got-the-ack-and-not-the-html-code-scapy)

Then i found somehow the function "sndrcv()" and i think its what i need.
(I think this function intended to layer 5..)
it gets 2 arguments. what are they?

Comment: Please wait for someone answering your question instead of posting duplicates. "No one knows the answer" that is very unlikely, people are also busy, be patient.